# Phonegap: display loadscreen between each click

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I've been trying to create a Phonegap application, and have made a pure CSS loading screen that will be shown every time the user clicks a button or a link. This will send a request to my webserver to get new data.

But the loading sceen only shows one time, and sometimes it don´t. Im testing on Iphone locally in Xcode.

Heres a sample code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".rbAnswerList .rbAnswer", function(event){
$('.sceen').addClass('display');
var hypo_id = $(this).attr('rel');
var qt_ID = $('h1.rbQ').attr('rel');
$.getJSON('http://app.mywebsite.com/folder/php/choose_ans.php?qt_id='+qt_ID+'&hypo_id='+hypo_id+'&uuid='+uuid, function(data){
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        if(value == 'Yes'){
            $.getJSON('http://app.mywebsite.com/folder/php/get_qt.php?uuid='+uuid, function(data){

                    $('.sceen').removeClass('display');
                $('.rbWindowQuestion').empty();
                $('.rbAnswerList').empty();
                if(data.reponse == 'No') {
                    alert('hello');
                } else {
                    $('.rbWindowQuestion').append('<h1 class="rbQ" rel="'+data.qt_id+'">'+data.qt+'</h1>');
                    $.each(data.answer, function( index, value ) { 
                        $('.rbAnswerList').append('<li rel="'+value.hypo_ID+'" class="rbAnswer">'+value.qt_ans+'</li>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });
});
```

element 'sceen' will only be showd when it gets the second classname 'display', and run a css keyframe animation.

Any idea why and how I can fix this?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You have one addClass but possible noumerous removeClass calls. In some cases class won't be removed at all...

Comment: Well I do have addClass on two set of functions, it depends on the button the user clicks. But okey, so I should fix this with remove and add class. Any ideas? On how to solve this

Comment: Try moving your removeClass right after first call of $.each(){};
And better use toggleClass.

Comment: Thanks, will test this out. And play around with it! :D

Comment: I prefer use of distinct functions in such cases. 
`code`
showLoading(){
  if (!$element.hasClass('loading')) $element.addClass('loading')
}

Comment: Ah, that would be much better! Thanks, did not think of that :)